# Is it possible to patch method called on created previously mock?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I have fixture which create `mocker.Mock` instead of `gui.Menu` object during initialization of `gui.Buttons`. Reference is stored in `Buttons.menu` attribute. In my test I check if proper function is called in `gui.Buttons.add`. Parametrized test worked well until I met condition where method from `gui.Menu` should be called. Now there is a mock.

```
import pytest
from project import gui

@pytest.fixture
def buttons(mocker):
    mocker.patch('project.gui.tk.Frame.__init__', return_value=None)
    mocker.patch('project.gui.tk.Button')
    return gui.Buttons(mocker.Mock())


@pytest.mark.parametrize('value,patched',(
        (None, 'project.gui.show_no_connection'),
        (False, 'project.gui.Buttons.process_data'),
        (True, 'pytest.Mock.show_error'),
))
def test_add_calls_function(buttons, value, patched, mocker):
    mocker.patch('project.gui.Buttons.exist_check', return_value=value)
    mocked = mocker.patch(patched)
    buttons.add()
    mocked.assert_called_once()
```

With real object I could write `(True, 'project.gui.Menu.show_error')` inside `@pytest.mark.parametrize` instead of `(True, 'pytest.Mock.show_error')` which doesn't work and produces `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest.Mock'`.

I wonder if it is possible to `patch` created mock object in my fixture to make it work like other parametrized examples. Is it even possible? Correct me please if way how I understand it is wrong.

Tested code looks like:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

from project.connection import Database


def show_no_connection():
    msg.showerror('Error', 'Could not perform operation. Try again later.')


class Menu(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.form = Form()

    def show_error(self, message):
        self.form.clear()
        msg.showerror('Error', message)


class Form(tk.Frame):

    def clear(self):
        print('Clearing...')

    def get(self):
        return {'Title': 'Test', 'ISBN': 87327837823}


class Buttons(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, menu):
        super().__init__(menu)
        self.menu = menu

    def process_data(self, data, operation):
        operation(data)

    def add(self):
        data = self.menu.form.get()
        exists = self.exist_check(data.get('ISBN', None))
        if exists is None:
            show_no_connection()
        else:
            if exists:
                self.menu.show_error(
                    'Record with set ISBN already exists in database.')
            else:
                self.process_data(data, Database().add)

    @staticmethod
    def exist_check(number):
        if number:
            return Database().search({'ISBN': number})
        return False
```

Displayed error:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________ test_add_calls_function[True-project.gui.Gui.show_error] _________

buttons = <[AttributeError("'Buttons' object has no attribute '_w'") raised in repr()] Buttons object at 0x7f840114aa10>
value = True, patched = 'project.gui.Gui.show_error'
mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockFixture object at 0x7f840114ab90>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('value,patched',(
            (None, 'project.gui.show_no_connection'),
            (False, 'project.gui.Buttons.process_data'),
            (True, 'project.gui.Gui.show_error'),
    ))
    def test_add_calls_function(buttons, value, patched, mocker):
        mocker.patch('project.gui.Buttons.exist_check', return_value=value)
        mocked = mocker.patch(patched)
        buttons.add()
>       mocked.assert_called_once()
E       AssertionError: Expected 'show_error' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

tests/test_gui_buttons.py:88: AssertionError
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `(True, 'project.gui.Menu.show_error')`? `project.gui.Menu` now points to the mock, so it should work.

Comment: @MrBean-Bremen that was what I expected, but it is not working. I get `AssertionError: Expected 'show_error' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

Comment: Ah, ok - you have a local copy of `gui` in your test module that you use. Use `import project` and `project.gui.Buttons` instead. Check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: @MrBean-Bremen I tried it, but still same error appears.

Comment: @MrBean-Bremen I have added example which mimic my code structure and pasted full information from test failure.

Comment: Thanks - I now understood the problem. You are right, it won't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a possibility to handle this in the same test - you probably will need a separate test for the last call. The problem is that the menu is already mocked, and you need that specific menu mock to do the test for the function call (the function will be called from that mock instance).
Here is a possible working implementation:

```
import pytest

# don't use "from project import gui" here to not make a copy in the test module
# that would be used instead of the mocked one
import project.gui  

@pytest.fixture
def menu_mock(mocker):
    # gives the possibility to access the menu mock
    # we need the return_value to get the instance instead of the class
    return mocker.patch('project.gui.Menu').return_value

@pytest.fixture
def buttons(mocker, menu_mock):
    mocker.patch('project.gui.tk.Frame.__init__', return_value=None)
    mocker.patch('project.gui.tk.Button')
    return project.gui.Buttons(menu_mock)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('value, patched',(
        (None, 'project.gui.show_no_connection'),
        (False, 'project.gui.Buttons.process_data')
))
def test_add_calls_function(buttons, value, patched, mocker):
    # unchanged except for the missing parametrize case
    mocker.patch('project.gui.Buttons.exist_check', return_value=value)
    mocked = mocker.patch(patched)
    buttons.add()
    mocked.assert_called_once()


def test_add_calls_show_error(buttons, menu_mock, mocker):
    mocker.patch('project.gui.Buttons.exist_check', return_value=True)
    buttons.add()
    # you now have access to the mocked menu instance
    menu_mock.show_error.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I was hopeing to place this case inside that one parametrized test. Now I see, that it won't be possible.